# MVC Routing Issue. Url being mapped to the wrong route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-routing

I'm trying to map the route of a specific url via `MapRoute`.

Basically, if an incoming url from a 3rd party site, contains the word `Pharmacy` at a specific point in my url, I want to redirect them to a specific action.

My problem however, is it seems anytime I type in a url, regardless of whether or not it contains "Pharmacy", they're all falling into my `Pharmacy` maproute below.  Here's my code for routing.

Please **note**: `Pharmacy` in my 1st route listed below, is an additional item in my url, positioned in between the controller name (`ProviderSearch` in the example below this code) & the action name (`ByPlan` in the example below this code):

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
        string clientConstraint = @"^(?!(home|admin|api)$).*$";

        context.MapRoute(
                    "Pharmacy",
                    "{client}/{directoryType}/{controller}/Pharmacy/{action}/{id}",
                    new { controller = "ProviderSearch", id = UrlParameter.Optional, directoryType = "", area = "Public" },
                    constraints: new
                    {
                        client = clientConstraint,
                        directoryType = new DirectoryTypeConstraint()
                    },
                    namespaces: new string[] { "MyNamespaceName.Controllers", "MyNamespaceName.Controllers" }
                );

            context.MapRoute(
                    "PublicDirectoryType",
                    "{client}/{directoryType}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                    new { controller = "App", action = "Index", client = "Home", id = UrlParameter.Optional, directoryType = "", area="Public" },
                    constraints: new
                    {
                        client = clientConstraint,
                        directoryType = new DirectoryTypeConstraint()
                    },
                    namespaces: new string[] { "MyNamespaceName.Controllers", "MyNamespaceName.Controllers" }
                );

            context.MapRoute(
                "PublicLegacy",
                "{client}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { controller = "App", action = "Index", client = "Home", id = UrlParameter.Optional, directoryType = "", area = "Public" },
                constraints: new
                {
                    client = clientConstraint,
                    controller = @"^(?!(admin)$).*$"
                },
                namespaces: new string[] { "MyNamespaceName.Controllers", "MyNamespaceName.Controllers" }
            );
    }
```

My goal is for the following:

1. The following url contains `Pharmacy`.  Therefore, it'll utilize my `Pharmacy` route:

   ```
    https://(MySite)/TheDynamicClientsName/public/ProviderSearch/Pharmacy/ByPlan?Benefit=ABC&BenefitGroup=ABC
   ```
2. The following url does NOT contain `Pharmacy`. Therefore, it'll ignore my `Pharmacy` route & instead use the 2nd route listed, named `PublicDirectoryType`:

   ```
    https://(MySite)/TheDynamicClientsName/public/ProviderSearch/Main
   ```

Like I said though, for some reason, that 2nd example is being routed through my `Pharmacy` route, which I don't want.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

IMHO it is easier to use the controller attribute routing

```
[Route("~/ProviderSearch/[action]")]
[Route("~/Home/[action]")]
public class HomeController: Controller 
{
[Route("~/ProviderSearch/Main")]
[Route("~/Home/Index")]
public IActionResult Index ()
```

and the same for pharmacy